# Using bxslider, is there some way to remove or hide the bullets at the bottom of the slide?

Tags: bxslider

I am using bxslider to make a simple carousel, one jpg per slide. Because I have 8 jpg's, there are 8 bullets that are displayed at the bottom of each slide. Is there some way for me to remove or hide them.

Comment: http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnail-pager-1

Answer (score 49):

There is an option of bxslider called "pager" that can take boolean true / false.
Use the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        pager: false
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there any option to show/hide according to hover? I couldn't see in the docs.

Comment: Since you're already using jQuery, I would suggest you to use an `hover` function instead of switching `pager` option. Something like `$(".mainImagesClass").hover(function() {
  $("#pagerID").show();
...
});`

Answer (score -4):

first load the bxSlider as usual,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
```

then only use the code below, otherwise the jquery will try to call perform the task without even implementing the slider.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        pager: false
    });
});
```