# Remove the pager from bxSlider

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I'm building a slideshow from http://bxslider.com/, but i want to remove the pager under the slide. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you post sample code and/or a fiddle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using bxslider, is there some way to remove or hide the bullets at the bottom of the slide?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255672/using-bxslider-is-there-some-way-to-remove-or-hide-the-bullets-at-the-bottom-of)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options list a pager option. It's set to true by default, but you can set it to false.

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  pager: false, // disables pager
  mode: 'fade',
  captions: true
});
```

Comment: if i want to do it using external js, is there any way ?